# Rspec ask if a public methodo calls a private one ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test if the public method create_file  calls the private method get_users called in the private method add_product_data

```
class UsersXmlGenerator
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def create_file
    builder = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new indent: 2
    builder.instruct!

builder.products do |xml|
  data.each do |pa|
    add_product_data(pa, xml)
  end


   end
  end


  private

  def add_product_data(pa, xml)
    xml.product_application do |xml|
      xml.users do |xml|
        get_users(pa).each do |user|
          xml.user do |xml|
            sections_for_user(user).each do |section|
              section.add_xml(xml)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def get_users(pa)
    pa.users.order_by_user.select(&:set_data?)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why? Unit tests should check for behavior, not implementation.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have a test to test the result of the method, but they asked me to do a test to test if this class calls that method and I can not understand how to test if the method is calling it

Comment: Dave is correct. There should be no knowledge of private methods outside of the class that defines them, including tests. There isn't really a ruby equivalent of the java `@PublicForTests` annotation precisely because this is a bad practice. If you absolutely have to do this, then you can make the method public. There are hacks around this, like using `my_uxml_generator.send(:private_method_to_test, args)`, but it's probably better to make the method public than to use a hack like that. Don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: @Jzr It looks to me like `get_users` is really a method that belongs to `pa`'s class -- e.g. maybe you could call it `pa.users_with_data`. In that case, it would make sense to test that **public** method like you are currently, and also test that the **public method of another class** is being invoked.

Comment: One of the main reasons to write tests is _refactoring_, i.e. changing the implementation without changing the external behavior. But this only works if you focus on the latter. If you tie your test to the implementation, you lock yourself in: attempts to modify the code will likely break the test or (even worse) may result in a false positive.

Answer (score 7):

I would argue that testing a specific implementation detail is an anti-pattern and absolutely useless. There is no benefit in having a failing test after a refactoring as long as the result is still correct.

Apart from that, I would do the following to test if a specific method is called:

```
subject(:generator) { UsersXmlGenerator.new(data) }

before do
  allow(generator).to receive(:add_product_data).and_return_original
end

it 'calls `add_product_data`' do
  generator.create_file
  expect(generator).to have_received(:add_product_data)
end
```